# Move Into Clinical Use

Tags: passive-voice, headlinese

A headline of a news article reads:

> [link](http://health.yahoo.net/news/s/nm/as-sequencing-moves-into-clinical-use-insurers-balk)
>   As sequencing ***moves into clinical use***, insurers balk

Do native speakers think that "move into clinical use" is not that well written?  Would "move into clinical use stage" be better?

Comment: It's fine as it is. Including the word ***stage*** would be unnatural at best (ungrammatical, imho, unless you include the article as *"...moves into **the** clinical use stage"*, which I don't much like).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is there a definition that fits "move into use"?

Comment: **Headlines aren't meant to be well-written**; they are meant to be brief. (Put another way, they are meant to be _concise_, not _precise_.) Prepositions and articles are frequently omitted. That's a leftover from the days when multiple articles were printed on the same sheet of paper, and space was valuable. So, no, your suggestion wouldn't be "better," because it would take up one extra word, perhaps causing the headline to not fit in the paper's print edition. (Whether or not online articles will eventually evolve into having more grammatical, wordy headlines is anybody's guess.)

Comment: @J.R. But grammatically speaking, my suggested alternative is better, right?

Comment: I find it difficult to answer that question when the phrase in question originates from headline, but I'll try. If I was aiming to improve the English, I might recommend changing "use" to "stage" – i.e., "As sequencing moves into clinical stages, insurers balk." Your suggested version sounds redundant. That said, I'm no expert in clinical trials; many professions have jargon that will sometimes sound a bit odd to the layman, but natural to the well-versed.

Comment: In this exact context arguably it doesn't make much difference in practice, but I think changing *use* to *stage* does represent a semantic shift. For which there's no obvious justification, imho. There's nothing in the least "clipped" or otherwise grammatically "loose" about the original. It's just that we're inclined to see it as "journalese" because (unavoidably) it's in the present tense, which would be slightly unlikely in most other contexts.

Comment: @meatie: [**use**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/use) noun, 1: *the action of using something or the state of being used for a purpose*. We're more likely to use [*come into*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22comes+into+use+next%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) rather than *move into* to figuratively refer to *changing* from some other state into that one, but it's largely a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 1):

> Do native speakers think that "move into clinical use" is not that well written?

It's OK. Native speakers might find it a bit passive. The technique isn't the agent that causes the move, some unidentified body of people are. However, as J.R. commented, newspaper headlines are a special form of English with separate conventions.

> Would "move into clinical use stage" be better?

No. You could improve this by inserting "the" before "clinical use" but it is still a clumsier alternative. Also, in newspaper headline English, brevity is paramount.